# Can't enter password to install Cordova Plugin from GIT

Tags: git, cordova, command-line-interface

I'm getting a really weird problem when I'm trying to install this plugin for my Cordova app. I use the command

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap.git
```

Which it accepts. The CLI asks me for my username, which I enter and then it asks my for my password. Here is the problem, I'm unable to enter my password. It won't accept any keyboard input here except for the enter key, which advances it without a password and causes an error.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here and how I could fix it?

Comment: Have you tried entering your password nevertheless and hit enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password is always hidden on command line. Still the keyboard input is accepted and can be submitted by pressing *enter*.

Answer (score 0):

The CLI is working fine. It is accepting your password. However, you are trying to access a nonexistent GIT repo. I assume that GitHub is thinking the nonexistent repo is private, and is asking you for a password. Probably Eddy Verbruggen has a few of these. You can confirm this if you use the CLI and type this:

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/WowIamSureThisWillNotWork.git`

This is something that you can also confirm if you try to clone a nonexistent Git repo from GitHub/EddyVerbruggen like this:

`git clone https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/WontWorkEither.git`

I think the correct GIT repo you are looking for is located here:

`https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme.git`